# Get paths of a tree but with all leaves o a node in one path in python

Tags: python, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

I have the following Node object

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(parent=None, data)
        self.__parent = parent
        self.__data = data
        self.__children = []

   # parent and data properties getters and setters are left out for convinience

   def add_node(self, node):
       node.parent = self
       self.__children.append(node)
```

so I have a tree that looks like this

```
            dummy_root(nodata)
             /         |      \
            A          B       C              
          /   \      /   \   /   \
         D     E    F    G   H    I 
        / \   / \  / \  / \ / \  / \
       K   L M  N O  P Q  R S  T U  V
```

I want to get all paths for all children of dummy_root. The tricky part that have not been able to figure out yet is that the leaf nodes need to belong to one path, e.g

```
paths = [
            [A, D, K, L], 
            [A, E, M, N], 
            [B, F, O, P], 
            [B, G, Q, R],
            [C, H, S, T], 
            [C, I, U, V]
]
```

I have found a way to get all paths but what I get is different paths for each leaf e.g

```
[A, D, K] and [A, D, L]
```

Python code:

```
 def __find_paths_recursive(node, path):
    path = deepcopy(path)
    path.append(node.data)
    if not node.children:
        pathss.append(path)
    for child in node.children:
        self.__find_paths_recursive(child, path)

for child in dummy_root.children:
    path = []
    find_paths_recursive(child, path)
```

Comment: @depperm corrected the tree.

Comment: So you get a list of lists of all different paths?

Comment: Yes but the leaf nodes must be in the same path.

Comment: Sorry to bother , but do I get it correctly? You have [A,D,K] and [A,D,L]  and want to get to [A,D,K,L]?

Comment: Yes that is correct. @themistoklik are you from Greece?

Comment: Is the tree garunteed to be complete?  can there be levels that are only partially filled, or parent nodes that have children that are both leaf nodes and inner nodes?

Comment: No there is no guarantee. For example there could be another node underneath dummy_root lets say W that could be a leaf

Comment: @Apostolos yes i am

Comment: @Apostolos what would the output look like in that situation?

Comment: paths.append([W])

Comment: See edit, I know I've seen this problem before in my DS course. Is preorder what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one iteration over your result `paths` with [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?#itertools.groupby)

```
result = []
for prefix, paths_iter in groupby(paths, key=lambda x: x[:-1]):
    result.append(prefix + [lst[-1] for lst in val])

print(result)
[[A, D, K, L],
 [A, E, M, N], 
 [B, F, O, P], 
 [B, G, Q, R],
 [C, H, S, T], 
 [C, I, U, V]]
```

Another way is to check if children are leafs during node processing:

```
def __find_paths_recursive(node, path):
    path = deepcopy(path)
    path.append(node.data)
    if not node.children:
        return
    if node.children[0].children:  # children are not leafs
        for child in node.children:
            self.__find_paths_recursive(child, path)
    else:
        path.extend(node.children)  # since all children are leafs
        paths.append(path)
```

Comment: the latter is the method I used I chose to use. groupby still gets me a bit confused. Will get the hang of it eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure if I'm getting this correctly, if not let me know

To go from `[A,D,K]` and `[A,D,L]` to `[A,D,K,L]`, 
you can make them into [OrderedSets](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) and get their [union](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).

You could add this step each time you're done processing leaf nodes.

Alternatively you can do a [preorder traversal](http://www.interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/TreeTraversals.html) for every child of your root node.